# How to refer to a section of comments in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am now using Doxygen to document my C++ codes. One thing I want to do is to write down some documents in one file, for example, `a.h`:

```
/*
*
*  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccddddddddd
*/
```

Then in `b.h`, I want to refer to this part of comments, then how could I do it? I image something like that in `a.h`:

```
   /*
    * @label comments_label
    *  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccddddddddd
    */
```

Then in `b.h`, I want to do something like that

```
/**
* I want to refer to some comments in a.h @ref comments_label
*
*
*/
```

Comment: In doxygen, things work the other way around.  You don't define snippets and then import them, but you CAN have a documentation file containing comment blocks associated to code in other files.  Or you can have loose documentation, and link to it from code-specific documentation, but that appears as a link rather than incorporating those comments at point-of-reference.

Comment: Did you have a look at \anchor ?